# Get an alert box to popup at the jquery event $(document).ready in smarty template

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I'm juuuuuust trying to get an pop up displaying test when the document is ready. I've managed to get google maps working on another page but somehow this is a lot of pain.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
[...]
        <script type="text/javascript" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        {literal}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert ("test");
});
        </script>
        {/literal}
    </head>
[...]
</html>
```

What should I do to get that popup message? I also tried copy pasting from my working jquery page without much success.

Comment: Hmmm the code looks fine. Not understanding smarty, does it include any other possibly conflicting javascript such as prototype?

Comment: Yes. There could be a conflicting issue here.
This page is a wrapper. It calls a body file which will then expand. This smarty file has the google map code which uses the $(document).ready event as well.

Am I allowed only one per page?

Comment: on the home page (where I'm testing it) there's no such thing as google maps etc... though. It's really just this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `<script href=...>` to `<script src=...>` works like a charm for me.

Comment: That worked! Wouh! Why did it work with href on my google map page? I guess I have to change it everywhere to make sure it always works now.

Comment: That would be weird, because a `src` attribute should have no effect on a `<script>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Does you javascript is enabled in your browser ?

You can type this:

```
$(function() {
  alert("test");
});
```